# How to reduce the openCV framework size in iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, opencv

I integrated [opencv 4.5.3](https://opencv.org/releases/) in iOS project following [this](https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1) approach. But the openCV framework's size is around **496** MB. It definitely increases my app size. I used only following methods from openCV. 
`UIImageToMat` 
`MatToUIImage` 
`cv::Mat` 
`cv::Vec4`

I used following modules as well.

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <opencv2/core/types_c.h>
#import <opencv2/Mat.h>
```

So, how to slim down openCV?

Comment: Check this link :) https://www.timpoulsen.com/2019/using-opencv-in-an-ios-app.html

Comment: My question was how to reduce opencv framework size. I Know how to setup openCV in Xcode. @Shamshirsaz.Navid

Comment: Did you get the final export to see the final output size? I know this has nothing to do with iOS, but I know that the size of Android in combination with OpenCV can be reduced to 8 MB (depending on what CPU architecture is chosen)

Comment: You're right. @Shamshirsaz.Navid . 
iOS app doesn't take the full size of openCV or any framework. I got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opencv.framework you quoted is 500M, the volume of this project will increase by 500M, but the archive APP volume will not be 500M, because you only use some symbols, and the others are optimized by XCode. If you are concerned about this volume, it is recommended to download the complete opencv project from the official website and rebuild it according to your needs.
You only need 'core. Core functionality' and 'imgcodecs. Image file reading and writing'.

Comment: Open opencv, download Sources. Use cmake build framework or static library and  change ccmake.

Comment: Can you elaborate the process please? I downloaded the source code but failed to integrate in XCode (Swift).

Comment: When I add .dylib files in my project I got this error  {


building for iOS, but linking in dylib file (Libraries/OpenCV/Lib/libopencv_core.4.5.3.dylib) built for macOS, file 'Libraries/OpenCV/Lib/libopencv_core.4.5.3.dylib' for architecture arm64

}

Comment: Thank You @Hao_Liang.                 
 Finally I realized that any app doesn't take full size of framework. 
And I don't know why some people come here(Stackoverflow) just to give negative reputation. Is it unclear question or repeated question? It's my mistake that I didn't know the inner mechanism of framework/Xcode.

Comment: You used the default cmake to generate a dynamic library for the MacOS platform, you should use "python ../platforms/ios/build_framework.py builddir". This can build .a and .framework for the iOS platform. By default, this static library is quite large, you can edit 'arch' in ‘platforms/ios/build_framework.py’.